# Elastica Results : how to get doctrine object when searching entire index

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

Continuing my discovery of FOSElasticaBundle.

Now I know how to retrieve actual doctrine entities :

```
    $finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.website.recipe');
    $results = $finder->find($search);
```

as opposed to Elastica\Result instances:

```
    $finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.index.website.recipe');
    $results = $finder->search($search);
```

It seems however I can call

```
$finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.index.website');
```

but I can't call

```
$finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.website');
```

So how do I retrieve doctrine object results for a search on the entire index ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have finder set to ~ in your config.yml file, you should be searching the entire website. Here's an example file that shows this in action.

```
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\ApplicationBundle\Entity\User
                    provider: ~
                    listener:
                        immediate: ~
                    finder: ~
```